# How can I make a full width wave in CSS

Tags: html, css, footer, css-shapes

I have been tasked with building a website. On this website they have footer in their mockup in the shape of a wave. See image below:

[image]

I can probably get away with not having the stroke or yellow line. The main issue is they would like to have this "footer wave" be 100% width. I was thinking there could be a CSS solution to this? Possibly recreating the shape in css? Is this possible?

Comment: try `background-image` with `background-size` set to 100%

Comment: SVG background, 100% width?

Comment: Not sure if re-sizing a shape like this is the best idea. Your shape and content that will overlay the shape will have a number of unwanted "collisions" at various sizes between shape edge and content. This might create an unnecessary about of work to "get right" at various screen sizes. All that assumes you want to maintain the aspect ratio in the X and Y directions. If you are willing to stretch the shape in the Y direction only and place any content below the lowest dip you can avoid a lot of the   collisions between shape edge and content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your footer once will become a complex image and it'll be hard to draw it with `SVG` and it could be cyclic (several repeated waves instead of only one) - you may create a template image and repeat it as a background. The template below is just an example and it's not ideally glued.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,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');
}
```

```html
<footer>
</footer>
```

Comment: You could as well use a svg encoded as a base 64 data URI for background image.

Comment: @svassr, the root idea is not in usage of base64 data or image URL. This wave is rather easy background but it's very possible that one day there'll be a much more complex image.

Comment: I do prefer your solution because of a better separation of concerns and I agree that the image could be more complex in the future. I just wanted to add that you can still use your solution with svg in case of a simple image which could be translated in vectors.

Answer (score 22):

You could use `svg`.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
footer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <svg viewBox="0 -20 700 110" width="100%" height="110" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path transform="translate(0, -20)" d="M0,10 c80,-22 240,0 350,18 c90,17 260,7.5 350,-20 v50 h-700" fill="#CEB964" />
    <path d="M0,10 c80,-18 230,-12 350,7 c80,13 260,17 350,-5 v100 h-700z" fill="#00273F" />
  </svg>
</footer>
```

Comment: Whoa. How did you get the path coords?

Comment: If you use Adobe Illustrator, you can actually create the path, save the file as SVG and in the dialog that pops up, you can get SVG code. I don't know if that's how chip did it, but that's one way (I'm sure other editors offers something similar).

Comment: @chipChocolate.py That's incredible! I guess the good thing is that now that I know Illustrator can do it, I can pick apart the code and eventually write it without software. You can also set Illustrator's output to only do one decimal as an option.

Answer (score 2):

Not the cleanest, but is done with pure css (pseudo effects):

```css
.wave {
  margin-top:50px;
  margin-left:-5%;
  position: relative;
  height: 70px;
  width: 110%;
  background: blue;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  overflow:none;
}
.wave:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100% 50%;
  width: 60%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  right: -5px;
  top: 46px;
    border-top: 5px solid gold;
}
.wave:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100% 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
  left: -2%;
  top: 40px;
  border-bottom: 5px solid gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="wave"></div>
```

- [Slightly Better attempt here](http://jsfiddle.net/1Lhz0996/)