# Flip an svg along the x-axis so it's upside down

Tags: css, svg

I am trying to flip this [SVG that I found on here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27785114/how-can-i-make-a-full-width-wave-in-css) so that the whitespace is on the bottom and the wave is on the top, but I can't figure out how to go about it. Any suggestions?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
footer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <svg viewBox="0 -20 700 110" width="100%" height="110" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path transform="translate(0, -20)" d="M0,10 c80,-22 240,0 350,18 c90,17 260,7.5 350,-20 v50 h-700" fill="#CEB964" />
    <path d="M0,10 c80,-18 230,-12 350,7 c80,13 260,17 350,-5 v100 h-700z" fill="#00273F" />
  </svg>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The simplest would possibly be to use a CSS transform to [rotate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotate) by 180 degrees. Since the initial value for [`transform-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) is `50% 50% 0` the rotation happens around the center. This avoids the need to actually modify the SVG.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
footer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <svg viewBox="0 -20 700 110" width="100%" height="110" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path transform="translate(0, -20)" d="M0,10 c80,-22 240,0 350,18 c90,17 260,7.5 350,-20 v50 h-700" fill="#CEB964" />
    <path d="M0,10 c80,-18 230,-12 350,7 c80,13 260,17 350,-5 v100 h-700z" fill="#00273F" />
  </svg>
</footer>
```

Note that this doesn't actually "flip", but rotate. If flipping is more appropriate, [scaleY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scaleY) with a value of `-1` can be used as well. It scales along the `transform-origin` as well, so the above holds here as well.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
footer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: scaleY(-1);
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <svg viewBox="0 -20 700 110" width="100%" height="110" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path transform="translate(0, -20)" d="M0,10 c80,-22 240,0 350,18 c90,17 260,7.5 350,-20 v50 h-700" fill="#CEB964" />
    <path d="M0,10 c80,-18 230,-12 350,7 c80,13 260,17 350,-5 v100 h-700z" fill="#00273F" />
  </svg>
</footer>
```

Comment: Yes! This is so simple and clean. Just what I was looking for. Thanks @mmlr :)

Comment: @dotwongdotcom simply pay attention as this will rotate the footer and may affect any content you will have inside the footer

Comment: Thank you, I couldn't find anywhere that: transform: scaleY(-1); is what I need it.
I didn't know that you can use negatives values...

Answer (score 6):

You may use scale transformation and adjust the viewbox like this:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
footer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <svg viewBox="0 -70 700 110" width="100%" height="110" preserveAspectRatio="none">
   <g transform="scale(1,-1)">
   <path transform="translate(0, -20)" d="M0,10 c80,-22 240,0 350,18 c90,17 260,7.5 350,-20 v50 h-700" fill="#CEB964" />
    <path d="M0,10 c80,-18 230,-12 350,7 c80,13 260,17 350,-5 v100 h-700z" fill="#00273F" />
    </g>
  </svg>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since 2022 you can use:

`transform: rotateY(180deg)`

and

`transform: rotateX(180deg)`

to flip along your desired axis